# SetAutoPageBreak not working or I am not using it correctly

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf, fpdf

SetAutoPageBreak not working or I am not using it correctly. It stops the first page just before the footer but then every page after that just print one line for 39 more pages.What am I doing wrong with this. I can not find anymore information about adding more info to make it work correctly. Here is a link http://notaryaccounting.com/doc-2.pdf to the output file so you can see

```
class PDF extends tcpdf
{
// Page header
    function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFont('dejavusans', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');
        $this->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
        // Move to the right
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(60);
        $this->Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='INCOME REPORT', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='', $stretch=0,
            $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='M');
        $this->Line (0, 13, 210, 13, $style=array());
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(5);
    }
// Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }

}
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE,20);
$pdf->SetFont('arial','B',12);

$y_axis = 20;
//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;
//Go to next row
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
//initialize counter
$pageLine = 0;
//Set maximum rows per page
$itemsPerPage = 5;

$result = $db->query("Select
  customers.name,
  signings1.signstart,
  signings1.fname,
  signings1.lname,
  signings1.city,
  signings1.state,
  signings1.samount,
  signings1.prtamount,
  signings1.faxamount
From
  customers Inner Join
  signings1 On customers.custid = signings1.custid
Where
  signings1.pid = 6 And
  signings1.done = 1
Order By
  customers.name ,
  signings1.signstart ");
$current=null;
foreach($result as $key => $income) {


    if($current!=$income['name']){

        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(0,68,150);
        $pdf->SetTextColor (252,252,252);
        $pdf->SetX(05);
        $pdf->Cell(200,6,'Customer:' . '               ' . $income['name'] ,1,0,'L',1);

        //print column titles for the current page
        $y_axis = $y_axis + 6;
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(0,68,120);
        $pdf->SetTextColor (252,252,252);
        $pdf->SetX(05);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Date:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(70,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(70,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Amount:',1,0,'L',1);
        $current = $income['name'];


 }
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(05);
    $pdf->SetTextColor (0,0,0);
    $total = $income['samount'] + $income['prtamount'] + $income['faxamount'];
    $name = $income['fname'] . ' ' .$income['lname'];
    $signdate=phpdate($income['signstart']);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$signdate,1,0,'L',0);
    //$pdf->Cell(10,6,$income['custid'],1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,$name,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,$income['city'],1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$total,1,0,'L',0);

} 

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: You have SetAutoPageBreak in your main file? But have you checked the SetAutoPageBreak in your fpdf.php? This two SetAutoPageBreak in two different file might be affecting your output. Try removing one of them.

Comment: I have modified the code above to show the rest of the code so you can see I don't have it set anywhere else. Or are you talking about someplace else that the SetAutoPageBreak could be set

Comment: Yes. Normally, if you're using FPDF, SetAutoPageBreak is already set in FPDF.php. So there's no need to set it again on your main file. (If you're requiring FPDF.php)

Comment: I removed my SetAutoPageBreak and it did not make any difference it did the same thing. I have never been able to make this work on this script or any other pdf. I had to turn it off and create my own code to create a new page. It would be nice to use this function but I can't figure out way it will not work

Comment: When I use FPDF, I only use FPDF (sometimes with mc_table). I'm not sure about TCPDF. And if I will set margins, spaces, etc., I modify the FPDF.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

require ('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
    function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'BI', 20);
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(60);
        $this->Cell(190,10,'INCOME REPORT','B',1,'C',0);
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(5);
    }
// Page footer
    function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}','T',0,'C',0);
    }

}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('arial','B',12);

$result = $db->query("Select
  customers.name,
  signings1.signstart,
  signings1.fname,
  signings1.lname,
  signings1.city,
  signings1.state,
  signings1.samount,
  signings1.prtamount,
  signings1.faxamount
From
  customers Inner Join
  signings1 On customers.custid = signings1.custid
Where
  signings1.pid = 6 And
  signings1.done = 1
Order By
  customers.name ,
  signings1.signstart ");
$current=null;
foreach($result as $key => $income) {


    if($current!=$income['name']){ /* PROCEED WHEN THE LAST NAME IS NOT THE SAME WITH THE CURRENT NAME */

        $pdf->SetFillColor(0,68,150);
        $pdf->SetTextColor (252,252,252);

        $pdf->Cell(200,6,'Customer:' . '               ' . $income['name'] ,1,1,'L',1);

        //print column titles for the current page

        $pdf->SetFillColor(0,68,120);
        $pdf->SetTextColor (252,252,252);

        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Date:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(70,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(70,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Amount:',1,1,'L',1);
        $current = $income['name'];


    } /* END OF IF, LAST NAME IS NOT THE SAME WITH THE CURRENT NAME */

    $pdf->SetTextColor (0,0,0);
    $total = $income['samount'] + $income['prtamount'] + $income['faxamount'];
    $name = $income['fname'] . ' ' .$income['lname'];
    $signdate=phpdate($income['signstart']);

    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$signdate,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,$name,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,$income['city'],1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$total,1,1,'L',0);

} /* END OF  FOREACH */

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: That Works how come it works in fpdf and not in tcpdf. It is suppose to be better and it runs with php5 and not php4 like fpdf. So I have been wasting my time with tcpdf

Comment: As I've said earlier, I'm not sure with TCPDF. Some people might be comfortable using it, but I prefer the simple and easy way to generate PDF. And the other one that I'm using is MC_TABLE. Good luck with your work.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am now using fpdf